# how to highlight item that has link to already selected menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

Extremely need help. I cant highlight selected (active) menu item. I created a module in Joomla that has images with links to menu items. It is like an additional menu.

```html
<script>
</script>
<div  class="links">
<a  href="/news" ><img src="images/news.png" alt="news" width="23px" style="width: 23px;"  /></a> 

<a href="/articles"><img src="images/articles.png" alt="articles" width="23px" style="width: 23px;"  /></a> 

<a href="/twitter"><img src="images/twlink.png" alt="tw" width="23px" style="width: 23px;"  /></a> 

<a href="/facebook"><img src="images/fblink.png" alt="fb" width="23px" style="width: 23px;"  /></a>
</div>
```

And now I would like to somehow highlight active menu, so if I on page "/news", the image "news" should have border at bottom (`.activemenu {border-bottom:1px #fff dotted}` )
What script I need to write between   to make each selected link to get class "activemenu" or border at bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer for my question on another site. Maybe some1 would like to use it

```js
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

```html
<nav id="nav" >
<a href="/news" ><img src="images/news.png" alt="news" width="23px" style="width: 23px;"  /></a> 

<a  href="/articles" ><img src="images/articles.png" alt="articles" width="23px" style="width: 23px;"  /></a> 

<a  href="/twitter" ><img src="images/twlink.png" alt="tw" width="23px" style="width: 23px;"  /></a> 

<a  href="/facebook" ><img src="images/fblink.png" alt="fb" width="23px" style="width: 23px;" title="ФЕЙСБУК" /></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this based on the information provided by you:

In your html:

```
  <a id="news" href="/news" ><img src="images/news.png" alt="news" width="23px" style="width: 23px;"  /></a>
```

In script:

```
var url = window.location.href.split("/")

if(url(url.length-1) == 'news'){

    var d = document.getElementById("news"); //you need to add id 'news' to your news anchor tag
    d.className += " activemenu";

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I inserted everything you wrote in my module, but it doesnt work for me( Maybe there should be some onclick that call a function?

Comment: Yes wrap it in a function and call it on every anchor tag click and on page refresh

Comment: I'm sorry for stupid question, but how can I do this? I am a full zero in java script(